# css mistake: hover event is fired also on child element

Tags: html, css, hover

this is my page:
http://www.clouderize.it/michele/category/uncategorized/contattaci/
The problem is on my menu.
If I hover on a sub-menu element (like michelepierri.it), the father:hover event is fired and the father element change his background.

I don't want this happens, so I want that the hover event is fired on menu-item only if I go with my mouse on menu element.

What I am doing wrong on my css?
Thanks.

Comment: Post your css code w.r.t to the menu. You are probably assigning a css to wrong element. Might a typo. Happened many times with me.

Comment: I replaced the shortened link with the actual link. There is plenty of space here, so there is no reason to use a shortened link, and we want to see where the link is going so we see that you aren't posting spam just to get impressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,I change

```
li.backgroundNormal{
```

to

```
li.backgroundNormal > a:hover{
```

Answer (score 0):

The "hover" CSS pseudo-states bubble up the DOM tree. Thus, if you hover an element, you automatically hover all of its ancestors.

Comment: but i don't want this how can I do?

Comment: The best option is to re-structure your DOM so that hovering the elements in question is mutually exclusive. You might also try playing around with the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) property but I have never used it to achieve a similar goal.